# NodeJS :Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/*var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});*/


/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

This code runs wll. But when I uncomment

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

it throws error:

```
Express server listening on port 3000

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/home/manish/Softwares/Node/annantNotification/annat-notification/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:531:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/manish/Softwares/Node/annantNotification/annat-notification/bin/www:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: Seemingly you are already running the server on the same port.  `pgrep node` / `netstat -a`

Comment: I ran `lsof -i :3000` but displayed nothing so i think nothing is using 3000 port

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine for me; are you sure it's 3000 and not a port set by another environment?  Is something blocking port 3000?

Comment: yes you are right it was conflict. Thank you